# How to recover disk image from a smartphone in "bootloop" state?

Tags: forensics, incident-response, data-recovery

I've been playing around on data recovery from devices and so far it worked well. Now I got this new situation that I don't know how to proceed in order to put my hands on the data. My old smartphone just crashed and entered in a bootloop. I couldn't boot into recovery either because the lower volume button of it is broken. Then I saw it slowly dying as it booted and restarted until the battery faded. All I want to do is recover its data, there are some photos/videos that wasn't sync'd to the cloud and also some other stuff. I don't know how could I (if it is even possible) to recover a disk image (like when we do by `dd`ing  the contents from `/dev` mapped devices) in these cases where I can't even boot it. So, my question is, how do I generate a disk image from it in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without recovery mode, nothing can be done because of the boot loop. However, all hope is not lost. Two options exist:

1)
[Fix a Stuck Button on Your Smartphone or Tablet [How-To]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-EVndPNaF8)

> In this video, I'll be showing you how to free up a stuck button on
>   your phone or tablet. By "stuck button," I mean the kind of
>   malfunction that happens when dirt and grime accumulate around a
>   button's housing, leaving you with a button that no longer gives you
>   that "clicky" feeling, making it difficult to press.
>
> Materials needed for this method are isopropyl alcohol, a Q-tip or
>   two, and some canned air.

I cannot foresee this doing much.

2)

Find a disassembly tutorial for your particular Android phone. Hopefully, the volume buttons are not actually broken, and rather something is preventing physical contact. Otherwise, it might still be possible to clean the circuit board without changing out the hardware.

This is quite restricting, as you need a functional volume rocker. Furthermore, repair difficult can vary from manufacturer and model.

Comment: I appreciate this is quite off-topic for the forum. But, I cannot see how to generate a disk image before entering recovery mode.